# regex inbetween two strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, parsing

I am looking for a regex that will help me match text between two strings.

I have the following string

```
Daily Update From: x.mydomain.local on DC01-PC
```

I am using the following RegEx

```
(?m)From: .*?on
```

But I want is to strictly pull the x.mydomain.local only from the string.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this.

Cheers,

Comment: What do you need the `(?m)` for? This modifier works only on the anchors `^` and `$`, you don't use them in your regex, so it is useless to have the modifier `(?m)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use a capture group (you'll then get `x.mydomain.local` in the first capture group):

```
(?m)From: (.*?) on
```

Or use lookarounds:

```
(?m)(?<=From: ).*?(?= on)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be the second capture group?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck nope, because `(?m)` isn't a capturing group. It just sets the `m` modifier.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck `(? ... )` are reserved for modifiers, you can have `(?s)`, `(?m)`, `(?i)` and so on, depending on what is supported. (You can even combine them: `(?smi)`) m is for multiline, s if for singleline, i is for case insensitive.